# Is there a way to register your app to some URLs just like in normal Android?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I would like to register my app to foursquare URLs and user would see a Intent chooser between browser and my app. It doesn't seem to work, default browser is always launched.

I was trying to call this code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("https://foursquare.com/v/san-francisco-international-airport-sfo/41059b00f964a520850b1fe3"));
startActivity(i);
```

And I registered this way in manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".IntentActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
      android:scheme="https"
      android:host="foursquare.com" />
</activity>
```

My app was never called, only browser. Are there Intent Choosers on Glass?

Comment: Maybe not. Glass is very limited in terms of user interaction, so make no sense to have apps distinct from cards, but at the end is an android, it should be there,

Comment: You may to set up a service that will handle "public" intents that the user may choose from ...  That is how one can share a picture with EverNote as well as with Google+ or others.